# Recorrer un array con php

Tags: php

tengo este codigo que genera un array automáticamente con los datos de una consulta:

```
$Codigos = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($RPedidos)) { $Codigos[] = $row['id']; }
$Idpedidos = implode(',', $Codigos);
```

lo convierto a valor separado por `,` porque luego hago una consulta con un `FIND_IN_SET`. Ahora aparte de esa consulta tengo que hacer otra con un loop para consultar cada uno de los códigos que me genera por separado.

y no tengo muy claro como hacerlo. Entiendo que tengo un array ya creado que se llama $Codigos pero no se muy bien la sintaxis que tiene ya que no puedo hacer un print_r para mostrar los datos porque estoy generando un pdf y no me deja hacer print_r.

Para hacer un loop que recorra todos los codigos que tendría que usar? el array $Codigos o el Implode separado por `,`?

lo he intentado así:

```
foreach($Codigos as $DContPedidos) {
    $CInPedidos = mysqli_query($Conectar, 'SELECT * FROM Pedidos WHERE `id` = '.$DContPedidos["id"].' ');
    $html .= 'Codigo Pedidos: '.$CInPedidos["codpedido"].'<br/>';
}
```

pero me da error `Warning: Illegal string offset 'id' in` con lo que entiendo que el fallo lo tengo en la consulta porque $ContPedidos no tiene un campo llamado id.

Si se hace asi ¿que dato le tengo que poner a `DContPedidos` para que me lea el contenido?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> no puedo hacer un print_r para mostrar los datos porque estoy generando un pdf y no me deja hacer print_r

Deberías desactivar los `header` que estableces para indicar que la salida es un `PDF` y de esa forma vas a poder visualizar el resultado de los `print_r`.

> Para hacer un loop que recorra todos los codigos que tendría que usar? el array $Codigos o el Implode separado por ,?

El valor devuelto por [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.implode.php) es un `string`, es decir, `$Idpedidos` no es un `array`.

> ¿que dato le tengo que poner a DContPedidos para que me lea el contenido?

La variables `$Codigos` es un arreglo de `ids`, es decir algo asi:

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

Por lo que, al iterar `$Codigos` el valor de `$DContPedidos`, seria `1`, `2`, etc.

Intenta hacer el `foreach` así:

```
foreach($Codigos as $id) {
    $CInPedidos = mysqli_query($Conectar, 'SELECT * FROM Pedidos WHERE `id` = '.$id);
    $pedido = mysqli_fetch_array($CInPedidos , MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $html .= 'Codigo Pedidos: '.$pedido["codpedido"].'<br/>';
}
```

Comment: Genial :) mil gracias